# limitTo angularjs with more complex expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display limited result of my `ng-repeat`, so first thing that come into my mind was limitTo. However its expression limitTo: 5 seem not solving my problem.

I wish I can do more complex thing with limitTo, eg. display limit of results of certain group, like display only 50 cars which from USA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple filters in the ng-repeat.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivaraj/76yc8/).

```
<div ng-repeat="people in peoples | filter:{country:'usa'} | limitTo:3">
            {{people.name}}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use :filter in your ng-repeat

```
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                         {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                         {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
Any: <input ng-model="search.$"> <br>
Name only <input ng-model="search.name"><br>
Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"><br>
Equality <input type="checkbox" ng-model="strict"><br>
<table id="searchObjResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
    <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

<kbd>[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)</kbd>

Comment: so i should write my own custom filter?

Comment: filter can limit numbers of result in ng-repeat? they neither hide it all or show it all right?